# Why do some frameworks use a longer include syntax?

Tags: php, include-path

It seems the following two code styles do the same job:

```
require_once './foo.php';
require_once './../bar.php';

require_once __DIR__.'/foo.php';
require_once __DIR__.'/../bar.php';
```

Clearly, the first form is shorter and cleaner. However, I see the second form in a lot of third party codes. Is there any reason to prefer the second form?

Comment: One is the current working directory, the other a script-relative reference.

Comment: @mario Any practical difference?

Comment: Any modern framework will use very limited `require` (even just a single occurrence to load in Composer's `autoload.php`) and then use `use` statements to include new definitions.

Comment: @PHPst __DIR__ makes it safe to run / call the file from any directory is executed besides the one where it resides.

Comment: Another problem is when you include one file from another. The `.` refers to the location of the script at the top of the include chain. When a file may be included form anywhere, you don't know what the current working directory is

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`__DIR__` is a [magic constant](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php), relative to the current script's file. The dot `.`, however, is relative to the current working directory, that could have been altered by [`chdir()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php), for instance.

Comment: Thanks. But I don't think that possibility make a reason to use the second form. `chdir()` is very rarely used.  Isn't?

Comment: @PHPst Even if it were only rarely used, that would still be one too much. And since it's defined in the context of frameworks, you want to make sure it's fool-proof, for any foreseeable possibility.

Comment: Yeah, "works most of the time, good enough" isn't a good attitude of someone developing a framework or tool for the community.

Comment: @DecentDabbler Yes, that makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

From [PHP.NET](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php):

> **`__DIR__`**
>
> The directory of the file. If used inside an include, the directory of
>   the included file is returned. This is equivalent to
>   `dirname(__FILE__)`. This directory name does not have a trailing
>   slash unless it is the root directory.

And then addressing your question in the comments:

> A lot of notes here concern defining the `__DIR__` magic constant for
>   PHP versions not supporting the feature. Of course you can define this
>   magic constant for PHP versions not yet having this constant, but it
>   will defeat its purpose as soon as you are using the constant in an
>   included file, which may be in a different directory then the file
>   defining the `__DIR__` constant. As such, the constant has lost its
>   *magic*, and would be rather useless unless you assure yourself to have all of your includes in the same directory.